# Convert boost ptime from local time to UTC

Tags: c++, datetime, boost, timezone

I have a `boost::posix_time::ptime` object (Boost v1.60) that has date and time information in the system's timezone. I need to convert this to a unix timestamp in UTC.

```
time_t convertLocalPtimeToTimestamp(const boost::posix_time::ptime& pt)
{
        using namespace boost::local_time;
        static const time_t t_null = 0;
        static struct tm* tm_local = localtime(&t_null);
        static time_zone_ptr zone(new posix_time_zone(tm_local->tm_zone));
        LOG(debug) << "Zone " << zone->to_posix_string();

        local_date_time az(pt.date(), pt.time_of_day(), zone, local_date_time::EXCEPTION_ON_ERROR);
        LOG(debug) << "local_date_time: " << az;
        LOG(debug) << "local_time: " << az.local_time();
        LOG(debug) << "utc_time: " << az.utc_time();
        struct tm t = to_tm(az);
        time_t ts = mktime(&t);

        return ts;
}
```

The result in my case (Europe/Madrid) is:

```
Zone CET+00
local_date_time: 2016-Oct-05 17:36:27.701162 CET
local_time: 2016-Oct-05 17:36:27.701162
utc_time: 2016-Oct-05 17:36:27.701162
1475685387
```

There are various errors in this result:

- Timezone should be detected as daylight saving: CEST (+0200) not CET (+0100)
- Even without DST detection, utc_time should be different from local_time.
- Finally the timestamp should represent UTC time, not local time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Boost stinks at this.  Have you considered https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fwiw, from this [free, open source library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html):

```
#include "chrono_io.h"
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto az = make_zoned("Europe/Madrid",
                         local_days{2016_y/oct/5} + 17h + 36min + 27s + 701162us);
    std::cout << "Zone " << az.get_time_zone()->name() << '\n';
    std::cout << "local_date_time: " << az << '\n';
    std::cout << "local_time:      " << az.get_local_time() << '\n';
    std::cout << "utc_time:        " << az.get_sys_time() << '\n';
    std::cout << floor<seconds>(az.get_sys_time()).time_since_epoch() << '\n';
}
```

And the output is:

```
Zone Europe/Madrid
local_date_time: 2016-10-05 17:36:27.701162 CEST
local_time:      2016-10-05 17:36:27.701162
utc_time:        2016-10-05 15:36:27.701162
1475681787s
```

One could also construct the `zoned_time` using `current_zone()` like this:

```
    auto az = make_zoned(current_zone(),
                         local_days{2016_y/oct/5} + 17h + 36min + 27s + 701162us);
```

Or:

```
    auto az = make_zoned(current_zone(), system_clock::now());
```

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I was looking for. But why do I have to download the database? Shouldn't that be the task of the operating system? I really need an offline solution.

Comment: Once the database is downloaded, the library will work offline.  However the database will become out-of-date within a couple of months (that's how often the database is updated).  You can choose to keep it up to date or not.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my Boost implementation of the problem to solve.

I did not want to use another third party library, and I had problems in Windows with jgaida's answer (tm_zone and tm_gmtoff are not members of tm).

I tested this code by changing the time zone in my Windows 10 PC several times.

The edge cases "(UTC-12:00) International Date Line West" and "(UTC+14:00) Kiritimati Island)" were also tested and the results were successful.

```
time_t convertLocalPtimeToTimestamp (const boost::posix_time::ptime& pt)
{
   using namespace boost::posix_time;
   using namespace boost::local_time;

   _tzset (); // This is needed if the time zone changes after the program starts.

   // Grab copies of the current time in local and UTC form.
   auto p_time = microsec_clock::universal_time (); // UTC.
   auto lp_time = boost::date_time::c_local_adjustor<ptime>::utc_to_local (p_time);

   // Calculate the difference between the UTC and local time and put it in a string.
   // This will yield "-07:00:00" for PST and "-08:00:00" for PDT.
   auto time_diff = to_simple_string (lp_time - p_time);

   // Convert the ptime to a local_date_time object using the local time zone.
   // We will create the time zone with the time difference string generated above.
   local_date_time local_time (p_time, time_zone_ptr (new posix_time_zone (time_diff)));

   // Calculate the difference in milliseconds between the UTC and local time.
   auto time_t_diff = to_time_t (p_time) - to_time_t (local_time.local_time ());

   // Return the given time in ms plus the time_t difference (to get the UTC ms).
   return to_time_t (pt) + time_t_diff;
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach @Zo_. Although I think you can remove the part where you create a new `time_zone_ptr`. I believe it is the same to `return to_time_t(pt - (lp_time - p_time));`.

Comment: The big diffenrence to my function is, that it takes the current timezone (and daylight saving status) from when you run the function. While my function gets the timezone from the `ptime` of the function's argument.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, I have found a simple way to detect the UTC Offset in Linux. It seems like `localtime` expects a not null timestamp to calculate the current timezone and offset. This way it works:

```
time_t convertLocalPtimeToTimestamp(const boost::posix_time::ptime& pt)
{
        time_t tt = to_time_t(pt);
        struct tm* local = localtime(&tt);
        LOG(debug) << "Timezone: " << local->tm_zone << " Offset: " << local->tm_gmtoff;
        return (tt - local->tm_gmtoff);
}
```

I know, there is a flaw, because I get the current timezone from the local time, so there will be an offset within the hour around the daylight saving time change. But for my purpose, that's not an issue.